# Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity

Tags: java, osgi-bundle, karaf, karaf-maven-plugin

when i try to install apache cellar (4.0.2) to apache karaf i get the follow error message:

> Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement
>   [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=cellar-hazelcas t;
>   type=karaf.feature; version="[4.0.3,4.0.3]";
>   filter:="(&(osgi.identity=cellar-hazelcast)(type=karaf.feature)(version>
>   =4.0.3)(version<=4.0.3))"

i try to install cellar with the follow command:

feature:install cellar

what is it the problem?

thx!